# Programmatically add and remove items in ListFragment android

Tags: android, android-listfragment, master-detail

I am working with the Android Studio Master/Detail template and I want to be able to add and remove items from the Master list with a button in my main activity. I can do it from within the xxxListFragment class if I use the onListItemClick method. But if I try to create a separate "public void onClickxxxbutton" method in the xxxListFragment class, then the button in my main activity can't see the callback in the fragment.

Putting an onClick handler in the java file for the main activity (xxxListActivity) does nothing (No crash, but no visible UI change).

```
public void onClickNewPatient(View view){
PatientList.ITEMS.add(new Patient("2", "B12", "Nosebleed", 12, "F"));
}
```

How should I be adding (and removing) items?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question(it seems like it should be a straight forward thing to do), but I've been searching for days and can't find an answer.

Comment: basically it this type of clickevent will get called in fragments, it will try to call in activity of the fragement. so better you can assign new listner to that control programmatically

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any adapter in your code to view patient list you should call "**adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**" to update your list

Comment: The only adapter is the one created on the fly in the onCreate method of the ListFragment class file `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Patient>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, android.R.id.text1, PatientList.ITEMS));`  Is there a way to get a reference to this adapter?

Comment: try this **((ArrayAdapter<Patient>)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: That doesn't work because my callback is in my main activity class not the ListFragmant class. I get an error that getListAdapter is not recognized.